# How remove scrollview programmatically (e.q. disable/enable wordwrap)?

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

XML (variant 1) - text WORD WRAP OFF:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How remove HorizontalScrollView programmaticaly, after that XML should be, like :
XML (variant 2) - TEXT WORD WRAP ON

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

What the appropriate way for do this:
Maybe use dynamic fragment ? Maybe use View.removeView ?
Or.... 
Please help...

Comment: You can avoid your problem by programmaticaly add the horizontalScrollView to the LinearLayout. Then you also can remove it and only set the edittext instead

Comment: yes, do a new HorizontalScrollView, add the EditText and then get your Content View (the LinearLayout) and add the HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

This code should remove the scroll view and put the item in it's place (For this to work be sure to add the id's to the view elements on the xml).

```
View bodyLayout = (View)m_dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_item);
ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView)m_dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_scroll);
ViewGroup topLayout =  (ViewGroup)scroller.getParent();
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = scroller.getLayoutParams();
int index = topLayout.indexOfChild(scroller);
scroller.removeAllViews();
topLayout.removeView(scroller);
topLayout.addView(bodyLayout, index, params);
```